# Function onEdit(e) works only for single cell edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using the below script to add a timestamp for every edit in Column A, however if i copied a range of cells and pasted to Column A, the script will work on the first cell only. Is there a way to capture the timestamp for all the edited cells?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var startRow=3;
  var targetColumn=1;
  var ws="Master Data";
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if (col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws ){ 
    var currentDate = new Date();
    
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).getValue() !== ""){
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).getValue() == ""){
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).setValue(currentDate);
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>2 && sh.getName()=="Master Data") { 
    var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var vs=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,2).getValues();
    vs.forEach(function(r,i){
      if(r[0].toString().length!=0 && !r[1]) {
        sh.getRange(i+e.range.rowStart,2).setValue(ts);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[onEdit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Sorry, i can't get this to work. Can we implement this on my script?

Comment: It works for me.  What does I can't get this to work mean?

Comment: the script doesn't do anything on my sheet at all.. also i tried using e.range instead of e.source on my script and when i changed it, it doesn't give anything as well.

Comment: what i understand is "vs.forEach(function(r,i){" starts another function out of onEdit.

Comment: Do you realize that you can not run onedit functions without an event object so either you supply it or let the onedit trigger supply it.  That's a long way of saying that you can't run these function from the script editor.

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper, it's working perfectly now. it wasn't working well as i wasn't using it only for timestamp. however it works perfectly :)